# Java test if correct class object is used

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method that read csv data, but I only use a specific class object:

```
class A {
    public void examine(Param[] params) {
        ZZZ zzz = new ZZZ();
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

The scenario that if someone changes by hand the method, test should fail (if is not ZZZ)
I'm new to testing.. how to write a test case that only passes when local variable uses a specific class object - case where only ZZZ is acceptable?

What I thinking is to modify method by adding:

```
class A {
    public void examine(Param[] params) {
        ZZZ zzz = new ZZZ();
        if (zzz instanceof ZZZ == false) {
            thow new IllegalArgumentException("not type of ZZZ");
        }
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

but then how to catch the Exception?

Comment: Java is a type-safe language. The variable `zzz` can only reference a `ZZZ`, therefore `zzz instanceof ZZZ` will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Turing85 the scenario is that when someone changes by hand the object class the test case should fail

Comment: We should test behaviour, not implementation. We should not care what the method does internally, as long as `examine(...)` behaves as expected.

Comment: If I looked at that code, and decided for some reason that I wanted to create a `YYY` instead of an `XXX`, I would change the type mentioned in `instanceof` as well.

Comment: @Turing85 not necessarily. If the instances were created by a different classloader it returns false. In this specific case that's of course not a problem.